# Why does the jar command with full path not behave as normal?

Tags: bash

If the working directory is `/home/user/myApp` and the command `jar -cvf app.war *` is run, the web archive is created with proper structure. However if instead of using `*` to specify the files the full path is used in the command by running `jar -cvf app.war /home/user/myApp/*`, all parent directories will be included in the archive as well.

In other words, `jar -cvf app.war *` correctly produces the following structure:

```
|
 - META-INF
|
 - WEB-INF
```

while `jar -cvf app.war /home/user/myApp/*` produces this structure:

```
|
 - home
    |
     - user
         | 
          - myApp
              |
               - WEB-INF
|
 - META-INF
```

Is this a bug? I can't think of any other command that behaves in this manner. This was tested with JDK 1.6.

Comment: Try the same with `ls` and you'll see that `jar` is not an exception.

Answer (score 1):

`*` is a special character in Bash (and other shells) used for [**glob expansion**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)

Bash expands an argument with globbing to a list of arguments which match the glob. The jar in your commands is receiving a list of expanded paths based on the globs, not expanding the globs itself. It is behaving the exact same way given two different sets of arguments.

```
# Glob
$ ls *
bar baz foo
# Not using Globbing
$ ls foo bar baz
bar baz foo
# Glob
$ ls /Users/will/temp/*
/Users/will/temp/bar    /Users/will/temp/baz    /Users/will/temp/foo
# Not using Globbing
$ ls /Users/will/temp/foo /Users/will/temp/bar /Users/will/temp/baz
/Users/will/temp/bar    /Users/will/temp/baz    /Users/will/temp/foo
```

Answer (score 0):

The `*` is a glob expression, which is expanded by the shell **before** executing the jar command. The jar command will never see the `*`.